# Double explode an array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

The string:

```
user:hello,user2:world
```

Desired Output:

```
$string = array(
   1 => array( 1 => "user", 2 => "hello"),
   2 => array( 1 => "user2", 2 => "world")
);
```

What I've tried (that doesn't work):

```
$string = explode(',',$string);
$string = explode(':',$string);
```

The error I get: `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string`

How can I get from the string to the desired output? Thanks!

Comment: ................. Didn't expect this question, use explode then a foreach loop then explode again ...

Comment: loop over the output from the first explode and explode the second time on each value.

Comment: when you explode a string you obtain an array of strings not a string

Comment: [Here you go](http://viper-7.com/uDgaIq).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

loop over the output from the first explode and explode the second time on each value.

```
$string = "user:hello,user2:world";
$array = explode(',', $string);

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $array[$k] = explode(':', $v);
}
```

Comment: just one little improvement: `foreach($array as &$v) $v = explode(':', $v);` see http://codepad.viper-7.com/5ExRH1

Comment: there is no need to make a reference out of $v, when he is reassigning the value through the key. either way works, to be honest

Comment: @michi I just prefer not to use references with foreach loops, especially with really generic variable names like `$v` simply because I don't like leaving the open reference to `$v` when the loop is done. If a value later on assigns to `$v`, it will still have the reference to the last entry from the loop unless you explicitly `unset($v)`. I find setting the value in the array using the key to be more readable as well. Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/tnIVSu If you leave out the possibility for the error of not unset'ing the reference, I feel it makes for better code.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: Right, this can be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

$string = "user:hello,user2:world";

$array = array_map(function ($input) {
    return explode(':',$input);
}, explode(',', $string));

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
$string = 'user:hello,user2:world';
$output = explode(',',$string);
foreach ($output as &$e) {
    $e = explode(':', $e);
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Don't forget to doing `unset($e);` after `foreach`. It may cause a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [example of user from manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#99167).

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ary = explode($delimiters[0],$string);
    array_shift($delimiters);
    if($delimiters != NULL) {
        foreach($ary as $key => $val) {
             $ary[$key] = multiexplode($delimiters, $val);
        }
    }
    return  $ary;
}

// Example of use
$string = "1-2-3|4-5|6:7-8-9-0|1,2:3-4|5";
$delimiters = Array(",",":","|","-");

$res = multiexplode($delimiters,$string);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
```