# PHP - Split string into rows for insert

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, split, explode

I have the following string:

$string=John Smith - Clearner - 1234$Bob Dillan - IT Man - 2453242$Sarah Clifford - Admin - 32423423

I need to split each persons name, occupation, registration number into 3 seperate columns into MySQL, each person is seperated by '$'

Desired result:

Col1 | Col2 | Col3

John Smith  | Clearner | 1234

Bob Dillan  | IT Man | 2453242

Sarah Clifford | Admin | 32423423

Now I believe we need to explode the string twice by '$' and  ' - '

I've managed to split '$' by doing the following:

```
$peeps = explode("$", $string);
foreach($peeps as $peep) {
$persons .= $peep;
}
$pnames = explode(' - ',$persons);
```

BUT I'm a complete newbie when it comes to exploding and the foreach loops

Any help would be amazing

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share of what you've tried so far?

Comment: You need to brake your string and after that  |  for diffrence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double explode an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576545/double-explode-an-array)

Comment: thank you for the link, tried to apply the code but i cant get it work...could you possibly draft a working code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your string, you can modify it in a simple way with array_map

```
$string="John Smith - Clearner - 1234$Bob Dillan - IT Man - 2453242$Sarah Clifford - Admin - 32423423"
```

If foreach is too difficult to grasp, as you have to modify the array you are traversing, try the functional approach, maybe it will result simpler to you.

`explode`, as you already know create an array splitting the input string with a separator:

```
$partial= explode("$", $string);
```

will result in

```
$partial= [ 
  "John Smith - Clearner - 1234",
  "Bob Dillan - IT Man - 245324",
  "Sarah Clifford - Admin - 32423423"
];
```

you can apply the same transformation to every element in an array with `array_map`. The transformation is encoded into an helper function:

```
function detail_splitter($string) {
    return explode(" - ", $string)
}
```

that can be leveraged as

```
$result =array_map(detail_splitter, $partial);
```

and the result will be:

```
$result = [ 
  ["John Smith", "Clearner", "1234"],
  ["Bob Dillan", "IT Man", "245324"],
  ["Sarah Clifford", "Admin", "32423423"]
];
```

which is an array of array. Every element of the array is processed by the helper function and splitted into a three elements array. The result is used to create a new array with the processed values ready to be further processed.

Obviously you can combine the steps into a single statement:

```
$result = array_map( 
    function ($p) { return explode(" - ", $p); },
    explode("$", $string);
);
```

Since now you do not have to transform the array further, but perform a task for every array element you can revert to foreach.

Note that I changed the parameter name from `$string` to `$p` to avoid to mess with the scope (for php it will just be fine, human programmers sometimes are not at ease with shadowing variable names).

There is a function, `array_walk` to perform a task on every element of an array but i think this task would be easier using a simple `foreach`.

You can address the different persons in a such way:

```
// $dbc is your db connection
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES (?,?,?);
foreach($result as $person) {
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $person[0]);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $person[1]);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $person[2]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I made some assumption with your sql statement but the mysql use it out of the scope of this question, I guess.

Comment: This did the job! thank you very much for taking the time to helpout! everything went to plan! I to use prepared statements so this slotted in perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
`$person_array = array(); $i=0;

$peeps = explode("$", $string);

foreach ($peeps as $peep) {
$persons = explode("-", $string);

foreach ($persons as $person) {

$person[$i]['name'] = $person[0]; 
$person[$i]['occupation'] = $person[1]; 
$person[$i]['number'] = $person[2]; 
$i++;

}   // inner each loop

}   // Outer each loop`
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do this in MySQL

```
UPDATE [table]
SET
 [col1] = SPLIT_STR([col], '$', 1),
 [col2] = SPLIT_STR([col], '$', 2),
 [col3] = SPLIT_STR([col], '$', 3);
```

Comment: It is not the require behaviour, that is just the first part of the procedure, and can be misleading, expecially for a newbie as stated in the question